# How can I extract these key/value pairs from this JSON node?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've been successfully using JToken and JArray to grab specific pieces of data, but I'm having one particular issue. The issues lie with extracting the values from the key/value pairs in my node 'work_unit.' You can see the node here in my JObject:

```
JObject testString = JObject.Parse("{"
                + "'Roofing': {"
                + "'Buildings': ["
                  + "{"
                    + "'BuildingId': 4,"
                    + "'BuildingName': 'what',"
                    + "'work_unit': '{\"RoofingBuildings\":\"1\",\"WindowsBuildings\":\"\",\"GutterBuildings\":\"\",\"InsulationMasterPrice\":\"\",\"SidingBuildings\":\"\"}'"
                 + "},"
                  + "{"
                    + "'BuildingId': 3,"
                    + "'BuildingName': 'Home'"
                 + "}"
                + "],"

                + "'Windows': ["
                  + "{"
                    + "'PerimeterDrawings': 56,"
                 + "},"
                  + "{"
                    + "'PerimeterDrawings': 55,"
                 + "}"
                + "]"

            + "},"

            + "'Window':"
                  + "{"
                    + "'poof': 3,"
                    + "'stall': 7"
                 + "},"

            + "'Products': ["
                  + "'Roofing',"
                  + "'Pooping',"
                + "],"

            + "'Garage': ["
                  + "{"
                    + "'roof': 3,"
                    + "'wall': 7"
                 + "},"
                 + "{"
                    + "'roof': 3,"
                    + "'wall': 7"
                 + "}"
                + "]"
        + "}");
```

I can get the entirety of 'work_unit' like so:

```
JToken jt= JO.SelectToken("Roofing.Buildings[0].work_unit");
^^ jt will contain:
{{"RoofingBuildings":"1","WindowsBuildings":"","GutterBuildings":"","InsulationMasterPrice":"","SidingBuildings":""}}
```

How do I get the "1" from RoofingBuildings? I've tried several methods, here are some, but they just end up being null.

```
string foo1 = (string)JTNewTest.SelectToken(".RoofingBuildings");
string foo2 = (string)JO.SelectToken("Roofing.Buildings[0].work_unit[0].RoofingBuildings");
```

Thanks in advance, I couldn't find my exact situation in any other online examples for some reason :/

Comment: The easiest way would be to create classes that are structure the same, then deserialized the JSON into your class type.  Then you access it just like normal with C# properties and enumerations, LINQ, etc.

Comment: unrelated: 
You can use multi-line string to get rid of the append on each line, makes code much more readable, and efficient.

Comment: Dou you have some particular interesting in using JToken and JArray? Because there are easier ways to solve you deserialization issue...

Comment: Hi @ps2goat,
I do plan on deserializing it into a class later. But right now I need to just extract it how I am.

Comment: @javier_el_bene and what ways are those? I was just using them because it seemed easy and straight forward.

Comment: @ps2goat is right indeed. The easiest way is deserializing directly to a class. Why do you want to deserialize "later"? Having your data in a strong-typed object from the very moment that you got your JSON makes easier any operation after that. I can help you with the class design...

Comment: The only reason I'm doing it later is because that JSON example is but a portion of what I'm dealing with at work. There is over 150 field names and what not and it's a third party setting it up so names keep changing and it's a real PITA constantly changing names in multiple places. So right now I'm just doing minor tests, and if anything I just want to know this answer out of pure stubborn curiosity haha

Comment: I have the class object basically set up with minor exceptions like for this node. What would the c# class object looking like that would deserialize the
 '{\"RoofingBuildings\":\"1\",\"WindowsBuildings\":\"\",\"GutterBuildings\":\"\",\"InsulationMasterPrice\":\"\",\"SidingBuildings\":\"\"}'"
part nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it like this, I assumed that the work_unit was supposed to be split up into it's own properties rather than being a string.. Hopefully I was correct in that assumption. Also made multi-line string for readability sake.

```
    JObject testString = JObject.Parse(@"
    {
        'Roofing': {
            'Buildings': 
            [
                {
                    'BuildingId': 4,
                    'BuildingName': 'what',
                    'work_unit': 
                    {
                        'RoofingBuildings':'1',
                        'WindowsBuildings':'',
                        'GutterBuildings':'',
                        'InsulationMasterPrice':'',
                        'SidingBuildings':''
                    }
                },
                {
                    'BuildingId': 3,
                    'BuildingName': 'Home'
                }
            ],
            'Windows': 
            [
                {
                    'PerimeterDrawings': 56,
                },
                {
                    'PerimeterDrawings': 55,
                }
            ]
        },
        'Window':
        {
            'poof': 3,
            'stall': 7
        },
        'Products': 
        [
            'Roofing',
            'Pooping'
        ],
        'Garage': 
        [
            {
                'roof': 3,
                'wall': 7
            },
            {
            'roof': 3,
            'wall': 7
            }
        ]
    }");

    var roofingBuildings = testString["Roofing"]["Buildings"][0]["work_unit"]["RoofingBuildings"];

    Console.WriteLine("RoofingBuildings: {0}", roofingBuildings);
```

Comment: Hey Austin, this is exactly what I was thinking. It works when I get rid of the single quotation marks before and after the '{' '}' symbols so that it's not a string. I was assuming this was a string on purpose and that I could access it but I guess not. I'll let the third party know to change this. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshuaRG1993, i guess you could access it, but you'd have to parse work_unit to a `JObject` also and then pull the information. However, it seems weird that it would be a string representation of JSON inside of JSON.. heh

Comment: Yeah, maybe it was a mistake made by the third party. And yeah that was my thought as well that I could serialize that string into a JObject and go through it again, but I also thought it was dumb. I emailed them letting them know the change would be appreciated. Thanks again for the response.